# Can not center the action bar title when the icon is shown

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, textview

The problem is I would like to center the action bar title and keep the back button at the same time. However, I found the title will not center if the icon is shown. I try align parent right , it works, but when I try center in parent it fail, it still at the right of the icon but not at the center of action bar

Fragment on create view:

```
 ActionBar ab = getActivity().getActionBar();
        ab.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        ab.setIcon(R.drawable.share_btn_home);
        LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = inflator.inflate(R.layout.action_bar, null);
        TextView title = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_title);
        title.setText(R.string.how_to_header);
        ab.setCustomView(v);
        ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        ab.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        ab.show();
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/action_bar_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for helping

Comment: Try setting the textview width to match parent and using center_horizontal and gravity

Comment: I would not recommend it, as it's not part of Android standard.